# Javascript not executed in a JSF + Primefaces page?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In this JSF page using Primefaces, I can't figure out why the javascript at the bottom of the page doesn't get called?

The function "initVisualization()" is contained in the progressbar1.js file loaded on top of the page.

Any hep would be appreciated!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>academiCV</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/otherpages.css" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="kinetic-v4.0.5.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="progressbar1.js" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="formID" prependId="false">
            <p:remoteCommand name="launchSearch" action="#{progressBarMessenger.processCalls()}"/>
            <p:remoteCommand name="checkUpdates" action="#{progressBarMessenger.checkUpdates()}"/>
            <p:poll interval="1" update="text,counter" oncomplete="checkUpdates(); updateVisualization();"/>
            <h:inputHidden id="counter" value="#{progressBarMessenger.progressMessage}"/>

            <div style="margin-left: 50px;font-size: 130%;">

                <div id="container"></div>
                <h:panelGrid id="text">
                    <h:outputText id="txt" value="#{progressBarMessenger.returnMsg()}" escape="false"/>
                    <h:commandButton id="button1" value="Look at probable mistakes" action ="#{progressBarMessenger.getNextPage()}" rendered ="#{progressBarMessenger.toggleButtonCorrections}"/>
                    <h:commandButton id="button2" value="Let our algorithms do the corrections, go to the final result" action ="#{controllerBean.skipPairs()}" rendered ="#{progressBarMessenger.toggleButtonCorrections}"/>
                    <h:commandButton id="button3" value="Check the list of co-authors of #{controllerBean.getSearch().fullname}" action ="#{progressBarMessenger.getNextPage()}" rendered ="#{progressBarMessenger.toggleButtonFinalCheck}"/>
                    <h:commandButton id="button4" value="Open #{controllerBean.getSearch().fullname}" action ="#{progressBarMessenger.getNextPage()}" rendered ="#{progressBarMessenger.toggleButtonReport}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </div>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(function(){
            initVisualization();

        }); //end ready
        //]]>
    </script>

</html>
```

Trace of the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:4009
Kinetic.Shape.fill kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:4009
Kinetic.Rect.drawFunc kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:4505
Kinetic.Shape.draw kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:4348
Kinetic.Container.draw kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:2857
Kinetic.Layer.draw kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:3586
Kinetic.Stage.add kinetic-v4.0.5.js?ln=js:3171
initVisualization progressbar1.js?ln=js:63
(anonymous function) progressBar1.xhtml:22
bZ jquery.js?ln=primefaces:14
b7.fireWith jquery.js?ln=primefaces:14
bG.extend.ready jquery.js?ln=primefaces:14
aF jquery.js?ln=primefaces:14
TableManager::findTables() content.scripts.c.js:11
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8084/AcademiCV/faces/progressBar1.xhtml".
```

And by the way, the first lines of this js function contained in progressBar1.js:

```
var stage;
function initVisualization(){
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 1100,
        height: 500
    });

    var barsLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var aLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var bLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var cLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var dLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var aRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: stage.getHeight() - 115 - 10,
        width: 245,
        height: 1,
        fill: 'green',
        //        stroke: 'black',
        //        strokeWidth: 0,
        name:'aBar'
    });
etc...
```

Comment: instead of `<script>` have you tried `<h:outputScript>` ? (btw, do you have any error in the js console?)

Comment: I haven't used the other JavaScript libraries you've included but seems like `$` is getting overridden by one of them and not being the one used in jQuery shipped with PrimeFaces.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I update with the trace of the console.

Comment: @seinecle, to be on the safe side, remove the func call from your xhtml and instead add the following to your progressbar1.js file : `$(document).ready(function () {
 initVisualization();
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all as Daniel said Remove your Java script from your page and include it in your Java script file

secondly and most important when you use Jquery with primfaces you should place the`<h:outputScript>` at the End of the `<h:body>` instead of the `<h:head>`.This way it will be loaded after the PrimeFaces-supplied jQuery/UI is loaded.

see this http://jsfspotlight.blogspot.com/2013/08/tip-of-day-including-jquery-script-in.html